# Showing Dirac Hamiltonian is hermitian

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, dirac-equation

I'm trying to show that $H_D = -i\boldsymbol{\alpha}.\nabla+\beta m$ is hermitian.

Its given that 
$$
\gamma^{0\dagger}=\gamma^0
$$
$$
\boldsymbol\gamma^\dagger=-\boldsymbol\gamma
$$

What i've done is:
$$
H_D^\dagger = +i\boldsymbol\alpha^\dagger.\nabla+\beta^\dagger m
$$
$$
=+i(\gamma^0\boldsymbol\gamma)^\dagger.\nabla+\beta m
$$
$$
=+i(\boldsymbol\gamma^\dagger\gamma^{0\dagger}).\nabla+\beta m
$$
$$=-i(\boldsymbol\gamma\gamma^0).\nabla+\beta m
$$

Well clearly i'm doing somthing wrong because $\boldsymbol\gamma\gamma^0\neq\gamma^0\boldsymbol\gamma$

Comment: $\nabla^\dagger = - \nabla$ and $\bf{\gamma} \gamma^0 = - \gamma^0 \bf{\gamma}$

Comment: why $\nabla^\dagger=-\nabla$ @Prahar

Comment: The operator $p = i \nabla$ is hermitian (this is the observable momentum), so $p = p^\dagger$, so $(i \nabla)^\dagger = (i \nabla)$. So there is an sign error in the first line.  At the end, you have to add a step, that is $\gamma \gamma_0 = -\gamma_0 \gamma = \alpha$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So the key is to understand that $\nabla^\dagger = - \nabla$. To see why this should be true, we go back to the definition of the adjoint of an operator, namely
$$\left< \phi \right|\left.  A \psi \right> = \left< A^\dagger\phi \right|\left.  \psi \right> \implies \int d^dx \phi(x)^* {\hat A} \psi(x) = \int d^d x \left( {\hat A}^\dagger \phi(x) \right)^* \psi(x)$$

In particular, for the differential operator

$$\int \phi^* \nabla \psi = - \int \nabla \phi^* \psi = \int \left( - \nabla \phi \right)^* \psi \implies \nabla^\dagger = - \nabla$$

Comment: Have you done integration by parts in $\int\phi^*\nabla\psi=-\int\nabla\phi^*\psi$?

Comment: Yes. I have assumed that the boundary term drops out.